# How do I get a running start after landing?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG, when you first hit the ground, your character usually crouches down and puts their hand on the ground to brace their impact.  During this animation, you cannot move and you have to wait for the animation to complete before you can begin walking.

Sometimes when I land, I've noticed that this animation doesn't happen, and I am able to begin moving practically immediately.  This is rather advantageous since it could mean the difference between picking up a gun that you and another player are racing for.  Is there anyway to make this happen every time you land?  Is it something to do with the angle of how I land?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not intended, but would like to see how you can do it reliably.

Comment: ooooooo I want an answer to this as when I drop at the school.... well its mayhem and every second matters.

Comment: I've had this happen a few times but it almost always was accompanied by me breaking through geometry so I would assume its a bug but thats a guess at best.  I'm glad I'm not the only one this has happened to.

Comment: @ZeroStack And Pecado casino too. You do not want to be the second person going in there :D

Comment: I suspect that this might have something to do with landing on something and bouncing off of it before the crouch animation can run. The only time I can remember going straight into the run is when my parachute cuts early and I bounce off the roof of a house, pretty consistent but not worth the fall damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impact of landing depends on the type of area you are landing on, the type of landing i.e. fast landing, slow landing, etc and the angle of landing. You can start running when the impact is low but when it is high, your character will try to brace himself.

Comment: Can you attach source of this informations?

Comment: I myself play PUBG so I know it... (:

Answer (score 0):

Basically PUBG calculates the landing from the height you originally jump from. So if you go to a height different than original the game will drop you before touchdown and you will brace yourself.

Also landing on terraces seems to work as it is flat and easy for the game to calculate. So there probably is not way to start running immediately except landing on terraces / airdrops.